# Pass a vector of distribution functions to calculate a mean per case in R

Tags: r, apply, do.call

I have several probability distribution functions defined using the `pdqr` package. Let say, they are `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
A <- as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1))
B <- as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 6, sd = 1))
C <- as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 2, sd = 2))
```

I have a large data.frame with a vector which has a character describing the appropiate PDF per case in a vector `distr`, let say:

```
df <- data.frame(distr = c("A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"))
```

I would like to generate the mean of each PDF per case. Individually this works like this for PDF `A`:

```
> pdqr::summ_mean(A)
[1] 3
```

Now I would like to generate the mean for each case based on the PDF set in `distr`. This means passing the PDF into `pdqr::sum_mean()`. I have tried the following with the resulting errors:

```
> df$distr_mean <- summ_mean(df$distr)
Error: `f` is not pdqr-function. It should be function.
> 
> df$distr_mean <- summ_mean(invoke_map(df$distr))
Error in A() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
> 
> df$distr_mean <- df %>%
+   pull(distr) %>%
+   summ_mean()
Error: `f` is not pdqr-function. It should be function.
```

So, either it doesn't understand that a pdqr-function is being passed, or it needs a x-value, which doesn't make sense, since I want the mean over the entire distribution, not a single x (passing a range like c(1:10) also doesn't work). Furthermore, I understand that any `apply` or `do.call` function only passes one single function, while I want to pass several different functions, given in a vector.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `distr` column as an argument to `mget`, which will return all the appropriate functions in a list. Just feed that list to `summ_mean` using `sapply`:

```r
sapply(mget(df$distr), pdqr::summ_mean)
#> A C A B B A C 
#> 3 2 3 6 6 3 2
```

Though inside `mutate` you'll need to tell `mget` which environment the functions will be found:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(distr_mean = sapply(mget(distr, envir = .GlobalEnv), pdqr::summ_mean))
#>   distr distr_mean
#> 1     A          3
#> 2     C          2
#> 3     A          3
#> 4     B          6
#> 5     B          6
#> 6     A          3
#> 7     C          2
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be easier to manage if you store your functions in a named list, rather than in the top level environment. From there, it's relatively easy to use `sapply` or `lapply` to calculate the mean for each function and then extract the results into df:

```
df <- data.frame(distr = c("A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"))

pdfs <- list(
  A = as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1)),
  B = as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 6, sd = 1)),
  C = as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 2, sd = 2))
)

means <- sapply(pdfs, summ_mean)
df$distr_mean <- means[df$distr]

  distr distr_mean
1     A          3
2     C          2
3     A          3
4     B          6
5     B          6
6     A          3
7     C          2
```

Or in one line:

```
df$distr_mean <- lapply(df$distr, \(x) pdqr::summ_mean(pdfs[[x]]))
```

Comment: This would work nicely, but I also want to have different combinations of PDFs passed to summ_mean...