# Pass distribution functions, named in vectors, to a function

Tags: r, function, vector, distribution

This question is a follow up on two questions I had answered before:

[Create the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362544/in-r-pass-multiple-distribution-functions-in-a-list-to-a-new-function)

[Calculate mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394343/pass-a-vector-of-distribution-functions-to-calculate-a-mean-per-case-in-r)

I have a couple of variables (`var1`, `var2` and `var3`), which have different distribution functions:

```
var1_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1))
var1_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 6, sd = 1))
var1_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 2, sd = 2))

var2_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 3))
var2_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 3, sd = 1))
var2_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 4, sd = 2))

var3_distr1 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 4, sd = 1))
var3_distr2 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 5, sd = 1))
var3_distr3 <- pdqr::as_d(function(x)dnorm(x, mean = 7, sd = 2))
```

To create proportional distribution function, to match the combination of two or three different variables whith their appropriate probablity functions I have created the next function I learned in the first question:

```
foo <- function(...){
  #set x values
  x <- seq(1, 10, by = 1)
  #create y values
  y <- 1L
  for (fun in list(...)) y <- y * fun(x)
  #create new PDF
  p <- data.frame(x,y)
  pdqr::new_d(p, type = "continuous")
}
```

So, if I want to create a proportional distribution function `var2_distr1__var3_distr3` of `var2_distr1` and `var3_distr3`  I can just do this: `var2_distr1__var3_distr3 <- foo(var2_distr1, var3_distr3)`, works like charm.

Now I have per for each variable, per case, I have selected the appropriate distrubution, using a simple `if_else`, which returns the appropriate distribution in a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("var1_distr1", "var1_distr3", "var1_distr1", "var1_distr2", "var1_distr2", "var1_distr1", "var1_distr3"),
                 var2 = c("var2_distr2", "var2_distr1", "var2_distr2", "var2_distr1", "var2_distr3", "var2_distr3", "var2_distr1"),
                 var3 = c("var3_distr2", "var3_distr3", "var3_distr1", "var3_distr1", "var3_distr2", "var3_distr3", "var3_distr1"))
```

If I want the mean for the relavant individual distributions per case for a single variable I can use this

```
df$var2_distr1_mean <- sapply(mget(df$var2_distr1), pdqr::summ_mean)
df$var3_distr3_mean <- sapply(mget(df$var3_distr3), pdqr::summ_mean)
```

which I learned in the second question.

However, if I want to get the mean of the proportional distributions given in `var1` and `var2` I get into trouble.

```
> df$var1_2_mean <- mapply(pdqr::summ_mean, foo(df$var1, df$var2))
Error in fun(x) : could not find function "fun"
```

While if I individually pass the distribution functions, this happens:

```
> df$var1_2_mean <- mapply(summ_mean, foo(var1_distr1, var2_distr2))
Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

As suggested by @Limey, if put the PDF's in a list:

```
PDFS <- list(var1_distr1 = var1_distr1, var1_distr2 = var1_distr2, var1_distr3 = var1_distr3,
             var2_distr1 = var2_distr1, var2_distr2 = var2_distr2, var2_distr3 = var2_distr3,
             var3_distr1 = var3_distr1, var3_distr2 = var3_distr2, var3_distr3 = var3_distr3)
```

However, when calling that (using this approach [apply-list-of-functions-to-list-of-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759367/apply-list-of-functions-to-list-of-values)) I get this:

```
> df$var1_2_mean <- foo(sapply(PDFS, mapply, df$var1, df$var2))
 Error in (function (x) : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]]) 
> sapply(PDFS, mapply, df$var1, df$var2)
Error in (function (x)  : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])
> sapply(PDFS, mapply, df$var1)
Error: `x` must be 'numeric', not 'character'.
> df$var1_2_mean <- foo(sapply(PDFS, mapply, paste(df$var1, df$var2, sep = ", ")))
 Error: `x` must be 'numeric', not 'character'. 
> df$var1_2_mean <- summ_mean(foo(sapply(PDFS, mapply, paste(df$var1, df$var2, sep = ", "))))
 Error: `x` must be 'numeric', not 'character'.

> df$var1_2_mean <- sapply(foo(mget(mapply(PDFS, sapply, df$var1, df$var2))), pdqr::summ_mean)
 Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'PDFS' of mode 'function' was not found 
> lapply(PDFS, function(x) x())
 Error in x() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I'm still missing something, and I believe it's on vectorisation. Might `invoke_map` work?

Comment: Why not pass the functions themselves, rather than their names?

Comment: Seems like a good plan, but how to store the functions in a vector? ‘ distr1 = c(A(), C(), etc.)’ ?

Comment: It would need to be a `list` rather than a vector.  And add the function (`func`) to the vector, not a function *call* (`func()`).  Try `foo1 <- function() { "Foo 1"}; foo2 <- function() {"Foo 2"}; funcList <- list(foo1, foo2); lapply(funcList, function(x) x())` to see how it works.

Comment: But I have hundreds of possible combinations of distributions, to create individual lists and call them seems hefty, while I think it can be vectorized

Comment: That's an element of the problem that you didn't specify in the question.  `utils::combn()` can generate combinations programmatically.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the `pdqr` package, so I can't solve your exact problem, but here's a proof-of-concept example that may be helpful.  As I mention in comments, you haven't specified your exact use case, but I do feel you are imposing constraints that make your life more difficult than it need be.  For example passing *function names* rather than *functions* to your summary function, using a data frame rather than a list, etc.

Anyway, start by defining some functions and store them in a list.

```
foo1 <- function() {"Foo 1"}
foo2 <- function() {"Foo 2"}
foo3 <- function() {"Foo 3"}

funcList <- list(foo1, foo2, foo3)
```

Now use `utils::combn()` to generate all combinations of two of these three functions and call each member of each pair in turn.

```
combn(
  funcList,
  m=2,
  FUN=function(combination) {
    lapply(combination, function(x) x())
  }
)
```

Giving

```
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
[1,] "Foo 1" "Foo 1" "Foo 2"
[2,] "Foo 2" "Foo 3" "Foo 3"
```

`combn()` takes the list of functions as input.  `m=2` requests the generation of all combinations of 2 elements from the list.  `FUN=` specifies a function to be applied to each combination.  The anonymous function supplied simply takes the supplied `combination` and simply calls each element of the combination in turn.

Comment: The trick is that the combination of which distribution functions to use, is given by multiple vectors in a data.frame. I've updated the question accordingly.