# calculate growth rate between columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

My data.table consists of an *a priori* unknown number of columns, eg.

```
 DT <- data.table("columnPred" = c(1,2,3), 
                     "column1" = c(7,8,9), 
                     "column2" = c(44,55,66))
```

I would like to calculate the change between the columns, ie.

```
DT[, delta1 := ((columnPred/column1)-1)*100]
DT[, delta2 := ((column1/column2)-1)*100]
```

How can I do this when the number of columns is unknown ahead of time?

Comment: You can use the technique I use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399775/pass-distribution-functions-named-in-vectors-to-a-function/73400632#73400632) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`, and doing element-wise division on DT (with the right-most column removed on the numerator, left-most on the denominator).

```
delta_col_names <- paste0("delta",1:(ncol(DT)-1))

DT[, (delta_col_names) := ((DT[,1:(ncol(DT)-1)] / DT[,-1])-1)*100]

   columnPred column1 column2    delta1    delta2
1:          1       7      44 -85.71429 -84.09091
2:          2       8      55 -75.00000 -85.45455
3:          3       9      66 -66.66667 -86.36364
```